# Changing/adding more content to a http request, by using an add listener in Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to add some stuff in every URLs that begins with some certain URL, is it possible to do that in Chrome?

I've been trying to use `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted`, but I couldn't see anything in the documentation

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/webRequest.html

that you can read or change the response

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(function(info) { 
    if(info.url.indexOf('mypage.com/page') > -1){
       //Do Something here to alter the response before its used in Chrome requests
       //or displayed 
    }

},{urls:["<all_urls>"]});
```

what do I do to alter this content? adding more stuff to it before it's put in the tab or in the iframe.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this can help:
http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: To clarify: do you want to alter the page itself (e.g., add some HTML), or just redirect the URL?

Answer (score 1):

A [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) is exactly what you want.  Content scripts are injected into every page that the browser visits and can be used to alter the HTML of the page.

You can use the `matches` property (or the `include_globs` property for greater control) in your manifest to control which pages get the script injected in them.

Your manifest should look something like:

```
{
    "name": "My extension",
     ...
    "content_scripts": [
        {
             "matches": ["*://*.mypage.com/page/*"],
             "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"],
             "run_at": "document_idle"
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

The `run_at` property specifies when the script should be injected; see the linked Chrome documentation for full details.